# Given list of booleans, compare and create a new list

Tags: haskell

let's say I have two lists, with one being all boolean:

```
[True, False, True]
[1, 2, 3]
```

Is there a function to compare these lists index-by-index, and create a new list of "true" values?

```
[1, 3]
```

Comment: Sounds like a great code golf task. How about `foldr ($) [] $ zipWith (\b i -> if b then (i:) else id) [True, False, True] [1..3]`

Comment: @Vektorweg :) `z bs = catMaybes . zipWith ((.Just).(>>).guard) bs`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This would do the trick:

```
fliterAccordingTo :: [Bool] -> [a] -> [a]
filterAccordingTo bs xs = map snd . filter fst $ zip bs xs
```

`zip` pairs the booleans with the values, `filter fst` picks only the pairs with `True` as first element, and `map snd` produces a list with only the second elements of the pairs (that is, the values).

Answer (score 8):

Also, list comprehension can be used very effectively here:

```
[ghci] let a = [True, False, True]
[ghci] let b = [1,2,3]
[ghci] [ b1 | (a1, b1) <- zip a b, a1]
[1,3]
[ghci]
```

Answer (score 5):

Not by default, but it's pretty simple to create one,

`zip` takes two lists and makes a new one with each element paired together. We can use `filter` to remove items that don't satisfy a predicate, and then `map` to apply a function to all elements of a list.

```
transform :: [Bool] -> [a] -> [a]
transform xs = map ???2 . filter ???1 . zip xs
```

Since this is looks a bit like homework, I'll let you fill in the `???`'s

`???1` should return true if the pair's first element is true and `???2` should return the second element.

This is the simplest solution, and we can expect that the compiler *should* fuse `map` and `filter` into a single list traversal.